# Wake for network access without Bonjour Sleep Proxy?

Tags: sleep-wake, bonjour

Is there a way to set some kind of "wake for network access" behaviour on my Mac without using a Bonjour Sleep Proxy?

I have a Mac with OS X 10.8.5, but no Apple TV nor Time Capsule or other stuff. I am happy with Unix solutions that require a bit of install and tuning on my laptops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wake on Lan works great on Macs with the following configuration :

- Connected using an Ethernet cable.
- Port forwarding if you're behind a NAT Router.
- Enable wake on network access
- A sleepy Mac (not Shutdown, it has to be on sleep)

That's it !

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Indeed, a `wakeonlan` script obtained at [http://gsd.di.uminho.pt/jpo/software/wakeonlan/.] works perfectly fine. This now prompts a new question: what can I do to tell the waked-up Mac to **not go back to sleep too early**? At the moment, it only answers my pings for about 30 seconds before sleeping again.

Comment: Using a ssh session, I use `caffeinate` (It prevent the system from going to sleep)